# Regex found every words like __WORD__

Tags: regex

I'm trying ot get my head wrap around this for quite some time, but it seems that I can't...

I would like to match patterns like `__MY_WORD__`
The thing is it might have multiple pattern on the same string.

I have tried something like :

`for string: "__key1__message1__key2__message2"
regex: "__[^_]*__"`

it works fine : `{:match, [['__key1__'], ['__key2__']]}`

but as soon as I add an underscore to the "key" it mess everything up...

`for string: "__key_1__message1__key2__message2"
regex: "__[^_]*__"`

the result is completely different : `{:match, [['__message1__']]}`

Comment: Maybe you could just use [`__.*?__`](https://regex101.com/r/gRwZld/1)

Comment: @Aaron It is quite the same as I posted, but less efficient. I added the details to my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah I commented around the same time you answered, I agree your solution is better

Comment: Just another solution: `__(?<=__).+?(?=__)__`
https://regex101.com/r/Ktk3ES/1

Comment: @Kira your lookarounds are redundant, your regex will behave exactly like `__.+?__` (but probably be slower). The lookbehind is taken into account just after having matched `__`, so it will always match. The lookahead will be tested after each char the `.+?` consumes, but so would directly testing against the following `__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
__[^_]*(?:_[^_]+)*__
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oCzMer/1)

Actually, it is an [unrolled](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) `__.*?__` pattern, but also matches across line breaks, and is more efficient since `.*?` expands character by character, and the negated character classes grab entire portions of text at once.

**Details**

- `__` - `__` substring
- `[^_]*` - any 0+ chars other than `_`
- `(?:_[^_]+)*` - zero or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `_` - a `_`
  - `[^_]+` - any one or more chars other than `_`
- `__` - `__` substring

Basically, it matches `__`, then any chars other than `_`, and then any number of `_`+non-`_`s, and then `__`.